SonarCloud can't find .lcov file in GitHub Actions
I am using SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action in a GitHub Actions workflow, following the documentation, to analyze a TypeScript project, which has Jest.
My workflow has this block:
name: Build & Deploy main branch
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20.9.0
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Tests
        run: npm run test:coverage
      - uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}

In the sonar-project.properties file from my project, there is the configuration proposed by the documentation, too, to define the file path:
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info

When the step runs, it cannot find the .lcov file:
INFO: Analysing [/github/workspace/coverage/lcov.info]
WARN: Could not resolve 1 file paths in [/github/workspace/coverage/lcov.info]

Looking at the logs from the action, the step that generates the coverage outputs this:
info - 2024-09-22 17:36:23,071 -- > /home/runner/work/front-mfe-***/front-mfe-***/coverage/lcov.info

It seems that each step runs in a different folder. I cannot find a way to fix it, I have already searched but didn't find a solution on the official docs. Am I missing something?
Tried to change the configuration in the workflow and in the properties file but didn't work out.

Could you share the whole workflow where you are using the sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action action?

@GuiFalourd I have updated the question with the action.

I suggest following the README configurations shared in the action README file, for example, using fetch-depth: 0 with the actions/checkout, the projectBaseDir and eventually args in the sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action.
